# question regrading double cone

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

How to prove that [double cone](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleCone.html) is not a topological manifold.I think I have to do something with the meeting point of the two cones.

Comment: You're right. It looks like 2 copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$ glued at a point.

Comment: but what does it imply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By observation, the space around $(0,0)$ is giving us problems. In fact, it looks like 2 copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$ glued at a point.

Using this fact, show that any neighborhood around $(0,0)$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and clearly not $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any other $n$), by considering the image of the lower cone (without the apex) and the upper cone (without the apex), which are 2 disjoint open sets.

Hence, it is not a topological manifold.