# Why aren't two cones attached in their vertex a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In [this](http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/grnotes-two.pdf) general relativity lecture notes, on page two, it is claimed that two cones attached on their vertex do not constitute a manifold. I don't see why. So, why?

Comment: This is not well researched, I know what the question is from the title because it is __the__ example of "things that are not manifolds" in at least 3 books. THINK ABOUT THE DEFINITION (this usually comes right after it) - how can the vertex be locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a Google search for "cones joined at the vertex" would solve it. I checked, it does.

Comment: @AlecTeal it is irrelevant whether google solves it or not. Stack exchange is about getting a database of answered questions, regardless of where else they might be answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [question regrading double cone](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276784/question-regrading-double-cone)

Comment: Also of [The double cone is not a surface.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/578167)

Comment: So yes, it has been answered here, and you didn't search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a manifold is locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space. Think about an X-shape, with $p$ the cross point; locally around $p$, the X-shape does *not* look like Euclidean space, even though around every other point it is locally a line.

Answer (score 3):

Any connected neighborhood of the vertex becomes disconnected when the vertex is removed. The only Euclidean space in which such behavior is possible is the real line. And, clearly, the space you are trying to describe is not locally homeomorphic to the real line in general, since the veetex is the *only* point where this behavior happens.